# Add Custom Button in Print Dialog box

Tags: c#, wpf, printdialog

I am developing a WPF application, i want to generate a pdf and ask to user that user want to store it on disk or generate a print.
now i have create a pdf but in i don't know how to add custom button for store that pdf on disk, so can any tell me that how to add custom button in print dialog?

Regards,
Vinit Patel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant add custom button on Print Dialog Box, but you can try to create your own Print Dialog Box.